# How to upload video to s3 using API GW and python?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im trying to make a api which will upload video to s3 . I all ready managed to upload the video in s3, but the problem is the video file is not working . i checked  content-type of video file, and it's binary/octet-stream instead on video/mp4 . So i set content-type to "video/mp4" while calling put_object api, but it still not working.

I use Lambda function for putting the video to s3 . here is my lambda code -

```
import json
import base64
import boto3



def lambda_handler(event, context):
    

    bucket_name = 'ad-live-streaming'
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    file_content = event['content']
    merchantId = event['merchantId']
    catelogId = event['catelogId']
    file_name = event['fileName']
    
    file_path = '{}/{}/{}.mp4'.format(merchantId, catelogId, file_name)
 

    s3_response = s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_path, Body=file_content, ContentType='video/mp4')    

        
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        "merchantId":merchantId,
        "catelogId":catelogId,
        "file_name":file_name,
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example in [Upload binary files to S3 using AWS API Gateway with AWS Lambda | by Omer Hanetz | The Startup | Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/upload-binary-files-to-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-with-aws-lambda-2b4ba8c70b8e), it appears that you need to decode the file from base64:

```
file_content = base64.b64decode(event['content'])
```

Comment: Perhaps the rest of the article will help.

Comment: Actually i took help from that article . i followed every steps .... but no luck so far :( 
I used same lambda code on my django server, and it worked perfectly ,so i'm assuming something happening while video file pass through API GW .

Comment: You could try uploading a simple text file first (instead of a video), so that you can check whether the contents is uploaded correctly.